# Firebase + Swift: How to observe childAdded with WHERE clause?

Tags: ios, oauth

I have a query that I'd like to listen to:

1. On the orders table
2. where order.location_id = "abc123"

How would I add the WHERE clause?

```
FIRDatabase.database().reference(withPath: "orders").observe(.childAdded, with: { (orderSnapshot) in
  print(orderSnapshot)
})
```

I know I can filter after I receive the snapshot instead of before, but that would be a lot more expensive

Answer (score 0):

Firebase doesn't have a WHERE clause like you would expect in Swift, instead you create queries on the paths you are observing. This allows you to filter data from your database.

In your case if you want "where" order.location_id = "abc123" then you will need to use the **queryEqualToValue** method on your reference.

Since you haven't told us what your data structure looks like, I'm guessing you can do something like this:

```
FIRDatabase.database().reference(withPath: "orders").queryEqual(toValue: "abc123")
```

This is just an example to show you how the queryEqualToValue keyword allows you to filter your data based on an equality.

Good luck!

Comment: how would `queryEqual(toValue: "abc123")` know that i want `location_id` to equal "abc123" and not another field (order.name, order.whatever)?

Comment: @Edmund Hmm.. maybe you need to dig deeper into your data, using the .child syntax, for example .reference(withPath: orders).child(orderId).child(location_id).queryEqual...